# I need help debugging pls

Tags: python-2.7

```
# make a list

shopping_list = []

# print instructions how to use app

print("what should we pick up at store")
print("Enter 'DONE' to stop adding items")

while True:
    # ask for new items
    new_item = input("> ")

    # quit app
    if new_item == "DONE":
        break

    # add new items to list
    shopping_list.append(new_item)


# print out app
print("Here's your list:")

for item in shopping_list:
    print(item)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the exception I am getting, 
If you are using python 2 use `raw_input('> ')` 
and if you are using python3 use `str(input('> '))`

Comment: Thank you, actually my first time asking a question here

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation